# How to retain array "key" order when processing

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am building a simple array dynamically in PHP.

When I build the array, the key order is this (as an example):

- A6
- A1
- C7
- "" (or NULL)
- B3

Yet when I reference the array via `foreach()`, the array is ordered ("","A1","A6,"B3","C7").

How can I retain the original order of the array when processing via `foreach()`?

I assumed the key order would be the way it was built, but is seems that either `foreach()` indexes the order, or it gets sorted somewhere along the way.

Thanks for helping.

**CODE SNIPIT**

```
    // loop through 3rd set of query results
echo '<pre>'; /*this is here for my debugging*/
    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        if (empty($teamName[$row3['team']])) {
            $teamName[$row3['team']] = $row3['name'];
echo '&gt;'.$row3['team'].'&lt;<br />'; /*this is here for my debugging*/
        }

        if ($row3['id'] == $_SESSION['authenticated']['id']) $cssStyle =  ' myPick';
        else $cssStyle = NULL;

        $html[$row3['team']] .= '<li class="bcPicks' . $cssStyle . '">';
        $html[$row3['team']] .= '<span class="bcPicks_displayName">' . $row3['displayName'] . '</span>';

        if (!empty($row3['team'])) {
            $html[$row3['team']] .= ' in ';
            $html[$row3['team']] .= '<span class="bcPicks_paddingA">' . $row3['games'] . '</span>';
        }
        else {
            $html[$row3['team']] .= '<span class="bcPicks_paddingB"></span>';
        }

        if ($row3['points'] < 0) $cssStyle = 'negative';
        else $cssStyle = 'positive';

        $html[$row3['team']] .= '(<span class="bcPicks_' . $cssStyle . '">' . signedNumber($row3['points']) . ' points</span>)';
        $html[$row3['team']] .= '</li>';

    } // end while() loop through 3rd set of query results

    // free-up memory
    mysql_free_result($result);

print_r($html);echo '</pre>';var_dump($html);exit; /*this is here for my debugging*/
    foreach ($html as $key => $value) {...}
```

I can tell you that my `print_r()` and `var_dump()` both show that the order coming out of the `foreach()` is not the way it gets built.

**HERE IS A DUMP OF THE ARRAY**

```
>E5<
>E4<
><
Array
(
    [] => 
name1(0 points)

    [E4] => 
name2 in 5(-2 points)
name3 in 6(-2 points)
name4 in 7(-2 points)
name5 in 7(-2 points)
name6 in 7(-2 points)
name7 in 7(-2 points)
name7 in 7(-2 points)

    [E5] => 
name9 in 4(+8 points)
name10 in 7(+8 points)
name11 in 7(+8 points)

)

array(3) { [""]=> string(158) "
name1(0 points)
" ["E4"]=> string(1156) "
name2 in 5(-2 points)
name3 in 6(-2 points)
name4 in 7(-2 points)
name5 in 7(-2 points)
name6 in 7(-2 points)
name7 in 7(-2 points)
name8 in 7(-2 points)
" ["E5"]=> string(495) "
name9 in 4(+8 points)
name10 in 7(+8 points)
name11 in 7(+8 points)
" }
```

Above you can see that it is built 'E5', 'E4', and NULL
Yet the array dump shows it in NULL, 'E4', and 'E5' order

Comment: `foreach` doesn't rearrange your arrays. Are you sure that is the order they are in? Try a var_dump() on the array to verify...

Comment: I did a `print_r($myArray)` and it shows the array in key sorted order.

Comment: `foreach` will present the items from the array in the order in which they are stored. This is the order in which they were added, unless you have applied a sorting function to it.

Comment: @adnan.shammout Please stop posting the same comment on all questions.

Speaking about arrays - like @cillosis mentioned, PHP does not sort arrays automatically. You have to look for code which does sort() on your array somewhere. Try doing a `var_dump` before `foreach` and after and see the result. Or even better, post your loop here.

Comment: Re-check your code, some kind of sorting method is applied on the array

Comment: @adnan.shammout There's a polite way to write it, not childish leet-speak.

Comment: I do not do any sorting anywhere along the way...I'll post my code in the question above...give me a couple mins.

Comment: And...thanks for the drive by "down vote" with no explanation as to why.

Comment: Per my live example/result @DaveRandom...`foreach()` is not processing the array in the order built. Wonder why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, this can't be caused by `foreach`.

But I noticed that you fetch your data from a mysql_query result. 
Most likely your SQL Query orders that result.

Even if you don't put a `ORDER BY` manually into your SQL statement, MySQL will order the results according to some criteria, especially the primary key of the requested table. So, if your array key `$row3['team']` is the primary key in your DB table, this is the most likely explanation.

edit:
just saw your update with the script output.
hmm...strange indeed..
two observations:

- an empty string as index is ugly as hell, I'm surprised php allows it
- you only print the debug index under certain circumstances, could it be that the query result has multiple rows with the same `team` value? I'm not sure which index php would use as the most recent, if some indices in an array have their value overwritten multiple times

Comment: Thanks @cypherabe. I do have an ORDER BY on my query statement. The dump in my question clearly shows the order of processing is 'E5', 'E4', and NULL. Yet, the foreach() processes the array as NULL, 'E4', then 'E5' -- exactly the reverse order built. And I do not sort/re=-sort the array anywhere. Just a peculiar anomaly I guess.

Comment: Nevermind. I found the error in my code. Sorry to burden the community here.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe associative arrays in PHP are implemented as dictionaries where order of keys is not guaranteed. You could use data structure like this instead, using an indexed array:

```
$array = array(
    array("A6", "bar"),
    array("A1", "foo"),
);
```

And then use it like this:

```
foreach($array as $v)
    $v[0] // this contains the key
    $v[1] // this contains the value
```

Comment: But isn't that the same thing that I have @Shedal? I mean, I am building a simple 1-dimension array where your example is just taking it to a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: But in my case, the keys are ordered by an integer key... well, just try it and compare. I haven't used PHP for a long while now :(

Comment: Although I agree on the solution somewhat, the order of keys in PHP *is* guaranteed. According to the manual and my (extensive) experience: "An array in PHP is actually an ordered map."